# Is there a way to detect when an app opens from idle or from the main button in Ionic v1?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building a new feature in my app. My app is build with AngularJS, Cordova, and Ionic v1.

I am planning to add a pin code security feature to the app.

First of all I am not sure if the pin code screen needs to appear when the app comes back from being idle and when it has been closed. Is that true?

Is there a way to detect when the app is coming back from idle and from being closed? How would you route to the pin code page in your router if normally you would route to the home page? Can you set the default route during run-time?

I did see these though: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html

Answer (score 0):

The [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) fires when the native platform pulls the application out from the background. In your case, from idle to the background

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // Your logic to show PINPAD
}
```

Comment: How would you open a page from there though? Isn't that out of the scope of angularjs?

Comment: Sure you can, I assume this code goes in your main controller, and from there you can call $state.go